# Google cant find any pages in my mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, googlebot

Hi I have a homepage that is just now working with google.
When I type following into a google search box "site:http://www.nameofmysite.com", I get Page  not found. 
Google is not able to index a single page in my whole site. I have many pages in my site.

However if you just browse my site it looks good, things are working nicely.
I have a MVC 3 site, I have made it multilanguage and the language parameter en, sv, es etc, is reflected in the url, something like www.nameofmysite.com/en/ContactMail

I'm not posting any code, since I do not know if the problem lays in the code or something else. If anyone would like me to post code, then please let me know.

Hope someone can shed some light on to this.

Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nameofmysite.com&oq=site:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nameofmysite.com&gs_l=hp.3...523.3591.0.3952.5.5.0.0.0.0.127.411.4j1.5.0.les%3Bernk_timediscountb..0.0...1.1.3.psy-ab.ZXDHjOFx_hY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.b2I&fp=2184b17ab8900e33&biw=1008&bih=424

Comment: The name of the site is not: thenameofmysite, it was just an example. I will try to pay more attention to the answers people provide and mark them and solved if true. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454734/mvc-site-is-not-crawlable-by-main-stream-search-engines

Comment: thanks for the link, I have seen it already, however it does not provide clear help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had my questions answered in another thread. 
[International version of NerdDinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908429/international-version-of-nerddinner)

The problem was that in my basecontroller and global.asax file I had some code that was returning null values if fetched by google bot.